# TeXLive utility update fails

Tags: mactex, update, texlive-2023, tex-live-utility

I have just updated my Mac to Sonoma 14.1.1 and run the TexLive utility to update packages. (EDIT: problem is not restricted to Sonoma; see below.) It tells me it needs to update `texlive.infra`first, but that fails repeatedly.

I can see the error in the log, but I don't know what it means/how to fix it. Searches also don't reveal an obvious answer to this particular issue, that I can see....

Log follows:

```
2023-11-19 18:01:23 +0000 Notice +[TLMEnvironment initialize][1408] Welcome to TeX Live Utility 1.54, running under Mac OS X Version 14.1.1 (Build 23B81) with 10/10 processors active and 16.0 GB physical memory.
2023-11-19 18:01:23 +0000 Notice +[TLMEnvironment _checkProcessUmask][1408] Process umask = 022
2023-11-19 18:01:23 +0000 Notice __TLMProxySettingsChanged[1408]    Trying to find a proxy for https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet using PAC http://wpad/wpad.dat…
2023-11-19 18:01:23 +0000 Notice __TLMPacCallback[1408] Proxy list = (null)
2023-11-19 18:01:23 +0000 Notice __TLMPacCallback[1408] Error finding proxy: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "(null)"
2023-11-19 18:01:23 +0000 Notice +[TLMEnvironment updateEnvironment][1408]  Setting up a new environment for /usr/local/texlive/2023…
2023-11-19 18:01:23 +0000 Notice +[TLMEnvironment updatePathEnvironment][1408]  Using PATH = "(
    "/Library/TeX/texbin",
    "/usr/local/bin",
    "/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin",
    "/usr/bin",
    "/bin",
    "/usr/sbin",
    "/sbin"
)"
2023-11-19 18:01:23 +0000 Notice +[TLMEnvironment _checkSystemPythonMajorVersion:minorVersion:][1408]   Using python at '/Applications/TeX/TeX Live Utility.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3'
2023-11-19 18:01:23 +0000 Notice +[TLMEnvironment _checkSystemPythonMajorVersion:minorVersion:][1408]   Python version is 3.9.10 (v3.9.10:f2f3f53782, Jan 13 2022, 16:55:45) 
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]
2023-11-19 18:01:23 +0000 Notice +[TLMEnvironment updateEnvironment][1408]  Nothing to update for /usr/local/texlive/2023
2023-11-19 18:01:23 +0000 Notice -[TLMDatabase _downloadDatabaseHead][1408] Checking the repository version.  Please be patient.
2023-11-19 18:01:23 +0000 Notice -[TLMDatabase _downloadDatabaseHead][1408] Downloading at least 2048 bytes of tlpdb for a version check…
2023-11-19 18:01:23 +0000 Notice -[TLMDatabase _downloadDatabaseHead][1408] Downloaded 65536 bytes of tlpdb for version check
2023-11-19 18:01:23 +0000 Notice -[TLMEnvironment initWithInstallDirectory:][1408]  Looks like you're using TeX Live 2023
2023-11-19 18:01:23 +0000 Notice -[TLMEnvironment _checkForRootPrivileges][1408]    Root permission required for installation at /usr/local/texlive/2023
2023-11-19 18:01:23 +0000 Notice +[TLMEnvironment _logEnvironment][1408]    Current environment from /usr/bin/env:
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F7:0x0:0x52
__CFBundleIdentifier=com.googlecode.mactlmgr.tlu
CC_FOR_BUILD=no_compiler_found
COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
HOME=/Users/kfeuerherm
LOGNAME=kfeuerherm
PATH=/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
SHELL=/bin/zsh
SQLITE_EXEMPT_PATH_FROM_VNODE_GUARDS=/Users/kfeuerherm/Library/WebKit/Databases
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.4xhYKtXp6M/Listeners
TMPDIR=/var/folders/z0/kdddygjn5c9_b_pjh_xy1zf80000gq/T/
USER=kfeuerherm
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
2023-11-19 18:01:23 +0000 Notice -[TLMLogWindowController awakeFromNib][1408]   Loaded log window controller
2023-11-19 18:01:24 +0000 Notice -[TLMDatabase _reloadFromLocalFile][1408]  Reloading local tlpdb from file:///usr/local/texlive/2023/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
2023-11-19 18:01:25 +0000 Notice -[TLMDatabase _reloadFromLocalFile][1408]  Took 1.46 seconds to reload local tlpdb
2023-11-19 18:01:25 +0000 Notice -[TLMDatabase _downloadDatabaseHead][1408] Checking the repository version.  Please be patient.
2023-11-19 18:01:25 +0000 Notice -[TLMDatabase _downloadDatabaseHead][1408] Downloading at least 2048 bytes of tlpdb for a version check…
2023-11-19 18:01:26 +0000 Notice -[TLMDatabase connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:][1408]  redirected request to https://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
2023-11-19 18:01:26 +0000 Notice -[TLMDatabase _downloadDatabaseHead][1408] Downloaded 7897 bytes of tlpdb for version check
2023-11-19 18:01:26 +0000 Notice -[TLMEnvironment _getValidServerURL:repositoryYear:fromURL:][1408] Repository version appears to be 2023; a young TeX Live
2023-11-19 18:01:26 +0000 Notice -[TLMFaviconCache downloadIconForURL:delegate:][1408]  Will look for favicon at https://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/favicon.ico
2023-11-19 18:01:26 +0000 Notice +[TLMLaunchAgentController pathOfUpdatedAgentForVenturaStupidity][1408]    Checking to see if we need to rewrite the launch agent plist because Ventura sucks.
2023-11-19 18:01:26 +0000 Notice -[TLMMainWindowController _refreshUpdatedPackageListFromLocation:][1408]   Refreshing list of updated packages…
2023-11-19 18:01:26 +0000 Notice -[TLMFaviconCache connectionDidFinishLoading:][1408]   Finished downloading favicon of length 283
2023-11-19 18:01:27 +0000 Notice -[TLMMainWindowController _paperSizeCheckTerminated:][1408]    System paper size = letter, pdftex paper size = letter
2023-11-19 18:01:28 +0000 Notice -[TLMOperation main][1408] Successfully executed `/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr --machine-readable --repository https://www.preining.info/tlgpg/ update --list --all`
2023-11-19 18:01:28 +0000 Notice -[TLMOperation main][1408] start load https://www.preining.info/tlgpg/
finish load https://www.preining.info/tlgpg/
2023-11-19 18:01:28 +0000 Notice -[TLMMainWindowController _handleListGPGUpdatesFinishedNotification:][1408]    Found 0 tlgpg packages to update from https://www.preining.info/tlgpg/
2023-11-19 18:01:29 +0000 Notice -[TLMOperation main][1408] Successfully executed `/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr --machine-readable --repository https://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/systems/texlive/tlnet/ update --list --all`
2023-11-19 18:01:29 +0000 Notice -[TLMOperation main][1408] start load https://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/systems/texlive/tlnet/
finish load https://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/systems/texlive/tlnet/
2023-11-19 18:01:29 +0000 Notice -[TLMMainWindowController _handleListUpdatesFinishedNotification:][1408]   Critical updates detected: (
    "texlive.infra"
)
2023-11-19 18:01:35 +0000 Notice -[TLMMainWindowController _isCorrectDatabaseVersionAtURL:][1408]   Checking database version in case preferences have been changed…
2023-11-19 18:01:35 +0000 Notice -[TLMMainWindowController _updateAllPackagesFromRepository:][1408] Beginning infrastructure update from https://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/systems/texlive/tlnet/
2023-11-19 18:01:35 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation _synchronouslyDownloadURL:toPath:][1408] Downloading URL: https://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh
2023-11-19 18:01:35 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation download:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:][1408]    Download redirected to https://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh, expecting 0 bytes.
2023-11-19 18:01:35 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation download:didReceiveResponse:][1408]  Will download 9450968 bytes…
2023-11-19 18:01:36 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation download:didReceiveDataOfLength:][1408]  Received 20% of 9450968 bytes…
2023-11-19 18:01:36 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation download:didReceiveDataOfLength:][1408]  Received 41% of 9450968 bytes…
2023-11-19 18:01:36 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation download:didReceiveDataOfLength:][1408]  Received 61% of 9450968 bytes…
2023-11-19 18:01:37 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation download:didReceiveDataOfLength:][1408]  Received 81% of 9450968 bytes…
2023-11-19 18:01:37 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation downloadDidFinish:][1408]    Download of 9450968 bytes complete
2023-11-19 18:01:37 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation _downloadUpdateScript][1408] First line of downloaded file is: "#!/bin/sh"…good!
2023-11-19 18:01:37 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation _synchronouslyDownloadURL:toPath:][1408] Downloading URL: https://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh.sha512
2023-11-19 18:01:37 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation download:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:][1408]    Download redirected to https://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/systems/texlive/tlnet/update-tlmgr-latest.sh.sha512, expecting 0 bytes.
2023-11-19 18:01:37 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation download:didReceiveResponse:][1408]  Will download 153 bytes…
2023-11-19 18:01:37 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation download:didReceiveDataOfLength:][1408]  Received 100% of 153 bytes…
2023-11-19 18:01:37 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation downloadDidFinish:][1408]    Download of 153 bytes complete
2023-11-19 18:01:37 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation _compare512][1408]   SHA512 signature looks okay
2023-11-19 18:01:37 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation main][1408]   Checking code signature before running tlu_ipctask as root…
2023-11-19 18:01:38 +0000 Notice /usr/bin/codesign[1408]    /Applications/TeX/TeX Live Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/tlu_ipctask: valid on disk
/Applications/TeX/TeX Live Utility.app/Contents/MacOS/tlu_ipctask: satisfies its Designated Requirement
2023-11-19 18:01:38 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation main][1408]   Signature was valid, okay to run tlu_ipctask
2023-11-19 18:01:46 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation main][1408]   Invoking privileged task via AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges
2023-11-19 18:01:46 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3052]  dropped privileges to user nobody
2023-11-19 18:01:47 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation setWrapperPID:][1408] tlu_ipctask checking in:  tlu_ipctask pid = 3052
2023-11-19 18:01:47 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation setUnderlyingPID:][1408]  tlu_ipctask checking in: pid = 3054 (/var/folders/z0/kdddygjn5c9_b_pjh_xy1zf80000gq/T/TLMInfraUpdateOperation.ia9HEh/update-tlmgr-latest.sh --nox11 -- --debug)
2023-11-19 18:01:47 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3052]  tlu_ipctask: child HOME = '/var/root'
2023-11-19 18:01:47 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3052]  tlu_ipctask: current HOME = '/var/empty'
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3052]  Verifying archive integrity... All good.
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] 0%    44%    88%  100%  /var/folders/z0/kdddygjn5c9_b_pjh_xy1zf80000gq/T/TLMInfraUpdateOperation.ia9HEh/update-tlmgr-latest.sh: line 204: /dev/tty: Device not configured
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3052]  Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3052]  ./runme.sh: updating in /usr/local/texlive/2023...
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3052]  ./runme.sh: tlmgr version says this is TeX Live 2023,
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3052]  ./runme.sh: and this updater script created: Thu Nov 16 02:12:22 CET 2023.
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3052]  ./runme.sh: proceeding with tlmgr update.
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + test x = x--upgrade
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + echo './runme.sh: proceeding with tlmgr update.'
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + mv ./master/bin .
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + mkdir ./installer
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + mv ./master/tlpkg/installer/tar.exe ./installer
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + mv ./master/tlpkg/installer/xz ./installer
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + mv ./master/tlpkg/installer/wget ./installer
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + mv ./master/tlpkg/installer/lz4 ./installer
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + cd master
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + cd /usr/local/texlive/2023
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + tar xf -
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + tar cf - LICENSE.CTAN LICENSE.TL README README.usergroups index.html readme-html.dir readme-txt.dir release-texlive.txt texmf-dist tlpkg
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + t_instdir=/usr/local/texlive/2023/tlpkg/installer
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + t_xzdir=/usr/local/texlive/2023/tlpkg/installer/xz
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + t_wgetdir=/usr/local/texlive/2023/tlpkg/installer/wget
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + mkdir -p /usr/local/texlive/2023/tlpkg/installer/xz /usr/local/texlive/2023/tlpkg/installer/wget
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + src_tlpobj=master/tlpkg/tlpobj
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + tlpobjs=master/tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.tlpobj
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + test -n 1
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] pwd
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] ++ pwd
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + : 'here (/var/folders/z0/kdddygjn5c9_b_pjh_xy1zf80000gq/T/selfgz305423831):'
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + ls
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] bin
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] installer
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] master
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] runme.sh
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + : installer:
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + ls installer
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] lz4
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] tar.exe
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] wget
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] xz
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + : installer/wget:
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + ls installer/wget
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + : installer/xz:
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + ls installer/xz
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + : ROOT/bin=/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin:
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + ls /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] universal-darwin
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + for a in '"$ROOT"/bin/*'
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + test -d /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/universal-darwin
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] basename "$a"
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] ++ basename /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/universal-darwin
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + b=universal-darwin
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + test universal-darwin = man
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + echo './runme.sh: updating /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/universal-darwin ...'
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + tlpobjs='master/tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.tlpobj master/tlpkg/tlpobj/texlive.infra.universal-darwin.tlpobj'
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3052]  ./runme.sh: updating /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/universal-darwin ...
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + cd bin
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + tar cf - universal-darwin
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + cd /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + tar xf -
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + test -r installer/xz/xz.universal-darwin
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + test -r installer/xz/xz.universal-darwin.exe
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + echo universal-darwin
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + egrep 'win32|windows'
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] pwd
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] ++ pwd
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + echo './runme.sh: no xz.[universal-darwin][.exe] binary for /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/universal-darwin in /var/folders/z0/kdddygjn5c9_b_pjh_xy1zf80000gq/T/selfgz305423831/installer/xz.'
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] ./runme.sh: no xz.[universal-darwin][.exe] binary for /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/universal-darwin in /var/folders/z0/kdddygjn5c9_b_pjh_xy1zf80000gq/T/selfgz305423831/installer/xz.
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Warning tlu_ipctask[3052] + exit 1
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][1408] kqueue noted that pid 3054 exited (/var/folders/z0/kdddygjn5c9_b_pjh_xy1zf80000gq/T/TLMInfraUpdateOperation.ia9HEh/update-tlmgr-latest.sh --nox11 -- --debug)
2023-11-19 18:01:48 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3052]  child process pid = 3054 exited
2023-11-19 18:01:49 +0000 Notice tlu_ipctask[3052]  exit status of pid = 3054 was 1
2023-11-19 18:01:49 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][1408] exit status of pid = 3052 was 1
2023-11-19 18:01:49 +0000 Notice -[TLMAuthorizedOperation _runUntilChildExit][1408] kqueue noted that tlu_ipctask (pid = 3052) exited with status 1
2023-11-19 18:01:49 +0000 Notice -[TLMInfraUpdateOperation main][1408]  Removed temp directory "/var/folders/z0/kdddygjn5c9_b_pjh_xy1zf80000gq/T/TLMInfraUpdateOperation.ia9HEh"
```

Comment: Not sure if my recent experience is relevant -- I updated to MacOS 14.1.1 a few days ago, and at that point the TeXLive updates no longer worked. I ended up reinstalling MacTeX2023 from scratch; so far, so good.

Comment: @Mico This is a currently known problem with TL Utility and the script it runs to update `tlmgr` itself.

Comment: @AlanMunn - Many thanks for these pointers.

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks, worked like a charm.

Comment: It's not just Sonoma: it's happening right now under Ventura 13.6.1 (22G313)